# margin-right 25px ALL the page

Tags: css

I have `margin-right:25px` in the html tag but it doesn't work for the elements which have `position:absolute;left:0` for example.

Is there any way to do it with them?

Thanks and greetings.

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify how wide your element is, if it's 100% you could use:

```
position: absolute;
left: 0;
width: calc(100% - 25px);
```

Or have you tried using:

```
right: 25px;
```

Answer (score 0):

What if you changed left: 0; to left:25px;?

Setting margin on absolutely positioned element won't work.

Answer (score 0):

On the body of the page add:

```
body {
  padding-left:25px;
  padding-right:25px;
}
```

Inside of it add a container:

```
.container {
  position:relative;
}
```

...and place everything inside of it. Voila!